# LUG war games — suggested strategies?

Tags: linux, remote-server

My LUG on campus once in awhile holds a mock wargames on a VM. I'm trying to figure a way to get root access and make everyone else not be able to have root (king of he hill).

I have a few ideas, but people on these sites always seem to have ideas far better than mine.

In sum, how to, when root, become the only user with root on the system to maintain control with other root users doing the same.

Comment: What are your ideas?

Comment: If you haven't already looked at the FAQ (linked below) you should, as this is not a typical internet forum where starting a vague thread works. SE deals in specific answerable, focused questions to problems you face and ideas you are considering. Preventing root access can be that specific if we have an idea of what system you are targeting and what you need help with. You might like to read the [how to ask](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) page...

Comment: ...and you should also know you can edit your question at any point and questions *can* be re-opened and downvotes removed in response to a good edit.

Comment: @Adnam
create a script to kill the login of any user of groups root or wheel except the calling user.  Then modify system wide .bashrc to logout if the user is of group root or wheel.

Comment: @Adnam
At which point, then go in and remove all other users from the sudoers file, disable group wheel, re-enable user root, set root's password, and control complete.

Answer (score 5):

There is a time-proven strategy: learn, and then learn more. Go to the library, read technical specifications, spend time (thousands of hours at least) programming and trying things on your own computer. In the long run, this works better than just asking on the 'Ternet.

**Alternative strategy:** bribe the sysadmin. History teaches us that more places were conquered through treachery and corruption than actual warfare.

Comment: Kind of defeats the internet's purpose of collaboration...